# Как правильно говорить: учебники обложены или обвёрнуты?

Tags: грамотная-речь

Как правильно говорить: учебники *обложены*, *обвёрнуты* или вообще *в обложках*?

Comment: Правильно говорить: "обёрнуты" (без "в").

Comment: @Ленора08 Сравните. Мы говорим: шоколадное ( или медовое,  или грязевое ) обёртывание. Если можно обернуть человека, то можно обернуть и книгу.

Comment: Учебники обернуты в обложку, именно об**ё**рнуты, а не о**бв**ернуты.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом).

Answer (score 5):

Обложить можно больного подушками, горло может обложить налётом при ангине, можно обложить медведя в берлоге, можно обложить налогом и грубо изругать - тоже "обложить", только просторечное.

А вот книгу можно обернуть, значит, "книги должны быть аккуратно обёрнуты" или "книги должны быть в красивых обложках". Обвёрнуты - разговорное слово, не литературное.

Answer (score 1):

**Обернуть и обложить** –  многозначные глаголы, это желательно учитывать при ответе на вопрос. Проще всего получить информацию из словаря, хотя предварительно можно определить  значение по корням  и приставке:  **положить** что-то вокруг предмета или **обвить** предмет чем-то, покрыть его.

Из словаря:

**ОБЕРНУТЬ,** -св. кого-что. 1. **Обвить**, расположить вокруг чего-л. О. шарф вокруг шеи. Косы обёрнуты вокруг головы. Обернул ноги портянками. 2. **Завернуть во что-л., покрыть со всех сторон**. **О. книгу в бумагу.** О. посылку холстом. О. ребёнка тёплым одеялом.

**ОБЛОЖИТЬ,** - кого-что. 1. **Положить** что-л. вокруг; окружить чем-л. О. клумбу дёрном. О. больного грелками.  2. **Покрыть,** отделать поверхность чего-л.; выложить чем-л. Печи обложены старинными изразцами. 3. **Покрыть,** окутать сплошной массой. Тучи обложили всё небо. // Покрыть (горло, язык) белым налётом (при некоторых заболеваниях). Горло обложило. И т.д.

Итак,  обернуть книгу –  это, **поворачивая ее,**  **покрыть** бумагой со всех сторон. (Обвернуть книгу –  просторечный вариант). Ближайшее значение глагола обложить –  это **покрыть** **неподвижную** печь изразцами.

Answer (score 0):

Я не согласен с предложением считать "обертыванием" помещение книги в обложку. 
Немного посмотрел поисковиками - не обнаружил ни одного бесспорного употребления именно в таком смысле

Обернуть книгу можно - лентой подарочной или оберточной бумагой, газетой (в значении "завернуть", "упаковать"), но это другой смысл.

Семантически правильным было бы "обложить" (ведь от него и идет "обложка"), но слово это "занято" многими другими значениями, в требуемом значении в современном языке почти вышло из употребление, поэтому бесспорно правильно только ***"книги в обложках"***. "Обернутые книги" в этом значении - максимум разговорное.

Впрочем, в одном случае это значение сохранилось. "Обложить зверя" - окружить собаками или флажками. Сама охота при этом называется обложной. Подозреваю, что именно отсюда и произошло просторечное "обложить матом".